# how to show database detail error

Tags: php, cs-cart

How can I see database query error in cscart? I set debug mode in config.php and debug mode for smarty in admin panel, but it always show non-sense error "An error occurred". It is very difficult to debug the developing addons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. add

```
define('DEBUG_QUERIES',true);
```

in config.local.php file :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also see errors into the logs, but you need to enable logs for database

---

Valentin